# Is there a way to limit the number of Jenkins builds triggered by a Gerrit merge event that was submitted using "Submit With Parents"?

Tags: jenkins, events, triggers, jenkins-pipeline, gerrit

After completing a series of local commits into a local branch of a project using git and Gerrit, I push that series of changes into Gerrit for review and ultimately merge. In Gerrit, I see the "Submit With Parents" button for all but one of these commits. This is expected behavior, and I have come to understand why.

In Jenkins, I also utilize a Jenkinsfile to build out my pipelines and in doing so I also use the Gerrit Triggers plugin to react to the event stream in Gerrit. More specifically, I hook onto the merge event to trigger release ready builds for testing purposes.

When I submit each change individually, Jenkins triggers a build and moves along it's merry way building things one at a time. But... If I merge with parents (assume large feature implementation), Gerrit triggers an event for every single commit in the series. What I am curious to know, is if there is a way in either Jenkins or Gerrit to only handle the event from the child commit and omit the events for the parents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins/Gerrit have not a way to handle specifically this but I'll suggest some workarounds:

1) You could add a "Topic" to the Gerrit Trigger on Jenkins with something like a "build" value. Doing this, Jenkins will only build merged changes of this topic and you only need to add the "build" topic to the child change to let Jenkins know what commit you want to build.

2) You could change the Gerrit trigger from "Change Merged" to "Comment Added Contains Regular Expression" with something like a "build" value. Doing this, Jenkins will not build when the changes are merged and you can trigger the build from the child commit just adding a "build" comment in the child change on Gerrit.

I hope this helps